# Securing a Private Build Agent in VSTS

Tags: security, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using VSTS and a private build agent and I want to make sure that I am not opening my organization to attack. The build and deployment pipeline allow Powershell scripts to execute on premise. To protect against hackers I have done the following

- Limited the access of the service account that runs the VSTS Build agent
- Limited who can invoke a Build or deployment
- Avoided executing scripts as part of the build that are in git

We have linked our internal Active directory to VSTS, which means we have a single sign on from within our organization.

My question is what else can I do to secure my Build and release pipelines? Are there tools or scripts that can be used to monitor the build scripts and there use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set permissions with two aspects to make your build/release and the private agent secure:

1. Set permissions for build/release definitions

   Click `…` button for build/release definitions -> Security -> set detail permissions for groups or users -> Save changes.
2. Set permissions for agent

   You can also set different roles for groups and users for Agent queues and Agent pools.

More details, you can refer the document [Set build and release permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/policies/set-permissions?view=vsts).

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. I was thinking about additional measures such as restricting the IP ranges to only internal addresses, perhaps making an alert happen when the build or deployment definitions change etc. Do you have any other ideas that I can follow up on?

Comment: @AgentBristow There has no such notifications when build/release definition changed. But you can compare or revert the build/release definition with the original version. Details as: build/release definition -> History Tab -> compare difference or revert to an old version (as the example https://ibb.co/kh1XsT).